# No response from Dynamodb when used from lambda AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have two use cases
I'm using DynamoDB locally with nodejs and I can create/read/update/delete successfully, no problems

But
when I'm using DynamoDB with a lambda configured with a template.yml and with ASW Policies to read create update etc, I can't get response from DynamoDB, I just didn't enter in the callback

Here is the code :

```js
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "eu-central-1",
    });

    var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    console.log(`[TDF-Rankings] - Trying to put datas in db`);

    dynamo.put({
      TableName: 'tdf-rankings-dev',
      Item: {
        id: uuid(`${Checkpoint.rank_type}.${Checkpoint.season}.${checkpoint.type}.${Checkpoint.number}`),
        ...Checkpoint
        }
    }, (err, res) => {
      console.log(`[TDF-Rankings] - in the callback`);
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return err
      }
      console.log(res);
      return res
    })
```

The logs :

```
START RequestId: 1e4fb8f0-e081-106d-5c24-58fa931a5892 Version: $LATEST
2020-02-21T18:53:34.820Z        1e4fb8f0-e081-106d-5c24-58fa931a5892    INFO    [TDF-Rankings] - Trying to put datas in db
END RequestId: 1e4fb8f0-e081-106d-5c24-58fa931a5892
REPORT RequestId: 1e4fb8f0-e081-106d-5c24-58fa931a5892  Init Duration: 661.36 ms        Duration: 25.35 ms      Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 60 MB
```

But if I do this :

```js
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "eu-central-1",
    });

    var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    console.log(`[TDF-Rankings] - Trying to put datas in db`);

    const request = dynamo.put({
      TableName: 'tdf-rankings-dev',
      Item: {
        id: uuid(`${Checkpoint.rank_type}.${Checkpoint.season}.${checkpoint.type}.${Checkpoint.number}`),
        ...Checkpoint
        }
    }, (err, res) => {
      console.log(`[TDF-Rankings] - in the callback`);
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return err
      }
      console.log(res);
      return res
    })

    console.log(request);
```

I get this

```
START RequestId: 86bf81b5-687b-127c-07ec-c586c9b6fcae Version: $LATEST
2020-02-21T19:04:01.139Z        86bf81b5-687b-127c-07ec-c586c9b6fcae    INFO    [TDF-Rankings] - Trying to put datas in db
2020-02-21T19:04:01.192Z        86bf81b5-687b-127c-07ec-c586c9b6fcae    INFO    Request {
  domain: null,
  service:
   Service {
     config:
      Config {
        credentials: [EnvironmentCredentials],
        credentialProvider: [CredentialProviderChain],
        region: 'eu-central-1',
        logger: null,
        apiVersions: {},
        apiVersion: null,
        endpoint: 'dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
        httpOptions: [Object],
        maxRetries: undefined,
        maxRedirects: 10,
        paramValidation: true,
        sslEnabled: true,
        s3ForcePathStyle: false,
        s3BucketEndpoint: false,
        s3DisableBodySigning: true,
        s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: 'legacy',
        s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
        computeChecksums: true,
        convertResponseTypes: true,
        correctClockSkew: false,
        customUserAgent: null,
        dynamoDbCrc32: true,
        systemClockOffset: 0,
        signatureVersion: 'v4',
        signatureCache: true,
        retryDelayOptions: {},
        useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
        clientSideMonitoring: false,
        endpointDiscoveryEnabled: false,
        endpointCacheSize: 1000,
        hostPrefixEnabled: true,
        stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy' },
     isGlobalEndpoint: false,
     endpoint:
      Endpoint {
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
        port: 443,
        hostname: 'dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
        pathname: '/',
        path: '/',
        href: 'https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/' },
     _events: { apiCallAttempt: [Array], apiCall: [Array] },
     MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
     CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
     _clientId: 1 },
  operation: 'putItem',
  params:
   { TableName: 'tdf-rankings-dev',
     Item:
      { id: [Object],
        rank_type: [Object],
        season: [Object],
        stage_id: [Object],
        stage: [Object],
        name: null,
        km: [Object],
        ranks: [Object] } },
  httpRequest:
   HttpRequest {
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/',
     headers:
      { 'User-Agent':
         'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.585.0 linux/v10.18.0 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs10.x callback',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
        'X-Amz-Target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.PutItem',
        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256':
         'c19835b2095ecfc493cbb8bab91423932ab0db31b061278f6fa4e845d539c141',
        'Content-Length': 3461,
        Host: 'dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
        'X-Amz-Date': '20200221T190401Z',
        Authorization:
         'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAV2CIO56THGYBA35E/20200221/eu-central-1/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=7d1f4ef387e346d364f5021ebfd2e0365c5dffa6d18f66f6c924dbf85af5d650' },
     body:
      '{"TableName":"tdf-rankings-dev","Item":{"id":{"S":"79fe14cd-2a5a-577d-a011-5100af8e0193"},"rank_type":{"S":"ETG"},"season":{"N":"2019"},"stage_id":{"S":"68169852-8d13-521b-bd50-fc7eece13b4a"},"stage":{"S":"1400"},"km":{"N":"2319.3"},"ranks":{"L":[{"M":{"bib":{"N":"7"},"position":{"N":"1"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"0"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"14"},"position":{"N":"2"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"665000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"2"},"position":{"N":"3"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"1510000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"9"},"position":{"N":"4"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"1629000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"1"},"position":{"N":"5"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"1905000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"6"},"position":{"N":"6"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"1947000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"11"},"position":{"N":"7"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"2342000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"13"},"position":{"N":"8"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"2720000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"10"},"position":{"N":"9"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"2774000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"4"},"position":{"N":"10"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"3126000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"8"},"position":{"N":"11"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"3427000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"3"},"position":{"N":"12"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"4278000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"15"},"position":{"N":"13"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"5659000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"5"},"position":{"N":"14"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"6049000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"20"},"position":{"N":"15"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"6892000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"22"},"position":{"N":"16"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"7278000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"21"},"position":{"N":"17"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"7532000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"12"},"position":{"N":"18"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"7740000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"16"},"position":{"N":"19"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"9484000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"17"},"position":{"N":"20"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"9499000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"18"},"position":{"N":"21"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"11056000"}}},{"M":{"bib":{"N":"19"},"position":{"N":"22"},"penality":{"N":"0"},"rider_id":{"S":"db4e117f-7b52-5819-a80d-31ed011064be"},"time":{"N":"13628000"}}}]}}}',
     endpoint:
      Endpoint {
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
        port: 443,
        hostname: 'dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
        pathname: '/',
        path: '/',
        href: 'https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/',
        constructor: [Function] },
     region: 'eu-central-1',
     _userAgent:
      'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.585.0 linux/v10.18.0 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs10.x callback',
     stream:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [Array],
        outputEncodings: [Array],
        outputCallbacks: [Array],
        outputSize: 4111,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 3461,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: null,
        connection: null,
        _header:
         'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: aws-sdk-nodejs/2.585.0 linux/v10.18.0 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs10.x callback\r\nContent-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0\r\nX-Amz-Target: DynamoDB_20120810.PutItem\r\nX-Amz-Content-Sha256: c19835b2095ecfc493cbb8bab91423932ab0db31b061278f6fa4e845d539c141\r\nContent-Length: 3461\r\nHost: dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com\r\nX-Amz-Date: 20200221T190401Z\r\nAuthorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAV2CIO56THGYBA35E/20200221/eu-central-1/dynamodb/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=7d1f4ef387e346d364f5021ebfd2e0365c5dffa6d18f66f6c924dbf85af5d650\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        didCallback: false,
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] } },
  startTime: 2020-02-21T19:04:01.141Z,
  response:
   Response {
     request: [Circular],
     data: null,
     error: null,
     retryCount: 0,
     redirectCount: 0,
     httpResponse:
      HttpResponse {
        statusCode: undefined,
        headers: {},
        body: undefined,
        streaming: false,
        stream: null,
        _abortCallback: [Function: callNextListener] },
     maxRetries: 10,
     maxRedirects: 10,
     nextPage: [Function] },
  _asm:
   AcceptorStateMachine {
     currentState: 'send',
     states:
      { validate: [Object],
        build: [Object],
        afterBuild: [Object],
        sign: [Object],
        retry: [Object],
        afterRetry: [Object],
        send: [Object],
        validateResponse: [Object],
        extractError: [Object],
        extractData: [Object],
        restart: [Object],
        success: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        complete: [Object] } },
  _haltHandlersOnError: false,
  _events:
   { validate:
      [ [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function],
        [Function: VALIDATE_REGION],
        [Function: BUILD_IDEMPOTENCY_TOKENS],
        [Function: VALIDATE_PARAMETERS] ],
     afterBuild:
      [ [Function],
        [Function: SET_CONTENT_LENGTH],
        [Function: SET_HTTP_HOST] ],
     restart: [ [Function: RESTART] ],
     sign: [ [Function], [Function], [Function] ],
     validateResponse: [ [Function: VALIDATE_RESPONSE], [Function] ],
     send: [ [Function] ],
     httpHeaders: [ [Function: HTTP_HEADERS] ],
     httpData: [ [Function: HTTP_DATA] ],
     httpDone: [ [Function: HTTP_DONE] ],
     retry:
      [ [Function: FINALIZE_ERROR],
        [Function: INVALIDATE_CREDENTIALS],
        [Function: EXPIRED_SIGNATURE],
        [Function: CLOCK_SKEWED],
        [Function: REDIRECT],
        [Function: RETRY_CHECK],
        [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY] ],
     afterRetry: [ [Function] ],
     build: [ [Function: buildRequest] ],
     extractData:
      [ [Function: extractRequestId],
        [Function: checkCrc32],
        [Function: extractData],
        [Function] ],
     extractError: [ [Function: extractError], [Function: extractRequestId] ],
     httpError: [ [Function: ENOTFOUND_ERROR] ],
     success: [ [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT] ],
     complete: [ [Function: API_CALL], [Function] ] },
  emit: [Function: emit],
  API_CALL_ATTEMPT: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT],
  API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY],
  API_CALL: [Function: API_CALL],
  rawParams:
   { TableName: 'tdf-rankings-dev',
     Item:
      { id: '79fe14cd-2a5a-577d-a011-5100af8e0193',
        rank_type: 'ETG',
        season: 2019,
        stage_id: '68169852-8d13-521b-bd50-fc7eece13b4a',
        stage: '1400',
        name: undefined,
        km: 2319.3,
        ranks: [Array] } },
```

Great thanks if you can Help it's for Tour de france 2020, that begin in 5 month but end to end test are next week

Comment: Is your entry point function `async`?

Answer (score 1):

add a `.promise()` after the closing parenthesis of `dynamo.put`

e.g
`dynamo.put(...)`**.promise()**

Answer (score 0):

If your lambda is using async as entry point
you need to add promise in the end of the dynamoDB object such as `dynamo.put(...).promise()`

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
    const result = await dynamo.put(...).promise()
    console.log(result)
    return {....} // trigger response
}
```

If you lambda is not using async as entry point
you need to use callback style

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    dynamodb.put(..., function(result){
        console.log(result);
        callback() // ---> trigger response 
    })
}
```